# Why does this output display only the odd numbers in the given range (user input) in this for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int count;
    int range;
    cout << "Enter the range of two numbers" << endl;
    cin >> range;

    for (count = 0; count <= range; count++)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            cout << count << endl;
        }

    system("pause")
    return 0;
}
```

the output displays:

```
Enter the range of two numbers
9
1
3
5
7
9
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: what did you expect it to output?

Comment: Try stepping through your code in a debugger and it should become very obvious.

Comment: this would be a great time to learn how to debug your programs.

Comment: I expected: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know what `count++` and `count = count + 1;` do.

Comment: My suggestion would be to go through some C++ tutorials. There are many websites that offer free tutorials, and you don't even need an IDE for many of them.  I like that you seem to be starting with C++, though. It can get frustrating sometimes, but it's a great language to start with if you stick with it.

Comment: @adpro the problem with tutorials is until you have a decent grip on the language and its best practices you can't tell a good tutorial from one that will make you an even worse programmer.

Comment: @user4581301, I kind of agree with that. I was self taught and definitely didn't learn a lot of best practices to begin with. But I eventually learned what was good and what wasn't. I also went back to school. Having a good resource that will teach you properly is obviously best, and cuts down the learning curve, so a school setting or reputable tutorials are best, obviously, but it can still be done on your own. It just might take longer. Learning a bad thing and why it's bad later will also teach you a good lesson, so there's that too.

Comment: And, there are lots of podcasts that can be listened to. Like cppcast. Or software engineering podcast. Or coding blocks.  These podcasts often give suggestions as to what sites are good to learn from. Like HackerRank or ProjectEuler. I feel it's easier to find good coding tutorials now than it was in the late 90's when I was learning.

Comment: @adpro I should have taken that statement further and included my counter recommendation. Find out who the experts in the field are. Use their tutorials/teachings where possible. They can't cover all of the bases, so when you go looking for a wider net of tutorials, try to find ones that cite the experts or are backed by the experts. When you find you can filter tutorials by whether they follow the same principles as the experts, congratulations! You've graduated to recognizing good tutorials at a rudimentary level.

Comment: @user4581301, that's great advice for more advanced topics, for sure. So he/she should put that in his/her back pocket. But the user doesn't know how a basic for loop works, so we're talking about the most basic tutorials at this point. I would have to ask how the user would find who the experts in the field are, and how to know they are experts. Sites designed to offer beginner tutorials would suffice at first, then your advice would kick in after the user got to know more about the language and people in the field.

Answer (score 1):

count is incremented twice in each loop. Once in the loop iterator (the "for" line) and once where you set count = count +1;

First time round the for loop, count  = 0, then it’s incremented (1), then printed. Then incremented in the "for" line (2), incremented by count = count +1 (3) then printed.

Comment: Some questions should not be answered. This sort of mistake should be a learning experience for a new programmer.

Answer (score 1):

When you increment count in the for loop your incrementing the variable "count" not just the for loop itself.
In c++, a for loop that increments by one can also be written as:

```
int count = 0;
for(;count <= range;;){
//code here
count++;
}
```

So the code you have written actually increments the for loop like this:

```
int count = 0;
for(; count <= range;;){
//code here
count = count + 1;
count++;
}
```

Which adds 1 twice to count, which is the same as adding 2.
Thus, your loop skips over every other number giving you odd outputs.

Comment: It doesn't matter much, but you should reverse `count++;` and `count = count + 1;` in your second snippet. The `count++` will take place after the `count = count + 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying `count` in your loop (`count++`) as well as in the body of the loop `count = count + 1;` so of course it increases by 2 each iteration.

What did you expect?